# Decoding Ascii Binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles

So I've tried the code below and after running this code it simply prints " ". Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong, or what I could do to fix this

```
file1 = open("Binaryfile.bin","wb+")
v = bytes("Hello World","ascii")
file1.write(v)
v = file1.read()
v = v.decode('ascii')
print(v)
file1.close()
```

Comment: You did not rewind the file cursor. After writing it will point to the end of the file. Use [seek()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the write operation, your position in the file is still positioned at the end of the bytes you've just written.  So when you call `read` immediately, you read from the end of the file until, err.. the end of file.  Ergo, you read (and print) an empty string.

```
file1 = open("Binaryfile.bin","wb+")
v = bytes("Hello World","ascii")
file1.write(v)
file1.seek(0)   # <--- rewind file!
v = file1.read()
v = v.decode('ascii')
print(v)
file1.close()
```